# Update cms/pages for multistore

Tags: magento-1.7, cms-block, script, shell

I need to update one cms page, but I have the same identifier 'home' for three pages in different stores.
How can I update one page with need store.

My script has error: 'A page URL key for specified store already exists.';

```
Mage::app();
$cmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStore('need store')->load('home', 'identifier');
    try {
        $cmsPage->setRootTemplate('one_column');
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
      }
$cmsPage->save();
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `load()` does not care about the store id you set before, it just loads the first page it can find with the "home" identifier.

You can use `checkIdentifier()` to retrieve the page ID for a given identifier and store, then load the page by id:

```
$pageId = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->checkIdentifier('home', $storeId);
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($pageId);
```